# Define type for date component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Since I am new to typescript , can you please suggest me how can i define type for my date component (separator='')

```
export function getCurrentDate(separator=''){

  let newDate = new Date()
  let date = newDate.getDate();
  let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = newDate.getFullYear();
  
  return `${year}${separator}${month<10?`0${month}`:`${month}`}${separator}${date}`
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how you define this function in typescript

```
export function getCurrentDate(separator: string = ''): string{

  let newDate = new Date()
  let date = newDate.getDate();
  let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = newDate.getFullYear();
  
  return `${year}${separator}${month<10?`0${month}`:`${month}`}${separator}${date}`
  }
```

You can omit the type definition of the separator, typescript will automatically bind a type `string` to the separator since it has a default value of a `string` in an operation known as *type inference*, you can read more about type inference [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)